# Can't get PHPUnit working in PHPstorm

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php, phpstorm

I am new to phpunit and I am trying to get it working with PHP storm. I have added composer and I have added the phpunit dependency and the files are all there. But when I try call phpunit in the command line I get this error.

[image]

I can't figure this out because I have tried calling phpunit and I have tried going through the folders to the files phpunit and phpunit.bat. Here is a picture of the folders and files.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It displays an error since your php is not being recognized. In order to fix the problem, you need to add your php directory to your PATH Environment Variable.

[Screenshot of My System Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N0Km.png)

To verify that your php is now being recognized by the system, run the command `php --version` in your command prompt. It should display the version of your PHP